# How to log a predefined message in a Mule pattern

Tags: logging, mule

Im trying to log a message into the log file but my code does not appear to be working

What and i doing wrong or how can i proceed?

```
    <pattern:web-service-proxy name="serv" inboundAddress="${serverName}/services/Logradouros/PontoReferenciaServico" outboundAddress="${targetServer}/servicos/v2/PontoReferenciaServico.svc" wsdlFile="PontoReferenciaServico.wsdl">
</pattern:web-service-proxy>



<flow name="service" doc:name="service">

    <logger message="#[message.inboundProperties.Host] #[message.inboundProperties.version] #[message.inboundProperties.http.method] #message.inboundProperties.http.request] #[message.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS] #[message.inboundProperties.User-Agent]" category="mule.http.accesslog" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger">
    </logger>  
</flow>
```

That message doesnt show in the log file...

Comment: Also do you happen to ship a Log4J configuration with your application? Do you see the Mule logs for your application?

Comment: Hi David, im using Mule version 3.4.0 and no Log4j conf gile with my app, that is why i dont know why its not working...

Comment: If you replace the deprecated old-style expressions `#[header:INBOUND:Host]` with MEL `#[message.inboundProperties.Host]` does it fail the same? If you just put a plain text message? If you increase the level to ERROR?

Comment: Still not working did the changes and nothing happened...

Comment: improved the code so its more clear what is going on...

Comment: Are you sure the `service` is being called?

Comment: If it is not that way how do i log what a pattern do, like the pattern i show in that code?

Comment: The `service` flow appears to be completely disconnected from the pattern. What is its message source? Is it called by the pattern? Unfortunately, you can not put a custom logger in a pattern. As a workaround, you could create a NOOP transformer that logs and use it in the pattern.

Comment: i agree with the disconected part, i have no idea on what is a NOOP transformer, any tutorial or something to read?

Comment: NOOP == No Operation, ie the transformer doesn't transform anything, it returns its input as output.

Comment: Any example on how would i use that over my code so i could log some messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, there is no direct way to log messages flowing through a pattern. A workaround consists in creating a NOOP transformer that performs the logging needed and refer to this transformer in the pattern:

```
<scripting:transformer name="noopLoggingTransformer">
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        log.info "${message.getInboundProperty('Host')} ${message.getInboundProperty('version')} ..."
        message
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>

<pattern:web-service-proxy name="serv"
    transformer-refs="noopLoggingTransformer"
    inboundAddress="${serverName}/services/Logradouros/PontoReferenciaServico"
    outboundAddress="${targetServer}/servicos/v2/PontoReferenciaServico.svc"
    wsdlFile="PontoReferenciaServico.wsdl" />
```